# In Java what should be the regex, if i need the text withing the quotes as one element?

Tags: java, regex

My input string is:

```
apple, orange, "banana,cherry", peach
```

I need the output as:

```
apple
orange
banana,cherry
peach
```

I have tried using the regex as:

```
",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", -1
```

...in the `split()` method of Java, but I get the output as:

```
apple,
orange,
"banana, cherry"
peach
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Seems more like you need a csv parser. If this is .Net, there's a really good one in the VisualBasic namespace, called `TextFieldParser`.

Comment: You want to change that regex so it doesn't return the quotes?  No can do.  Just remove the quotes in a separate step, after the the `split()`.  Or use a CSV parser, which will remove them for you.

Comment: Thanks Alan, as Nyerguds said the regex was a monster to handle, so I went as per your suggestion to handle the output using Core Java replaceAll !

Answer (score 0):

This one should work, though regex is really something you should figure out by yourself. Gods help you if you ever want to change anything in it; since you didn't design this monster you'll probably have no clue how it works.

And a monster it is, believe me.

`\s*("?)\s*([^",]+?(\s*,\s*[^",]+?)*?)?\s*\1\s*(,|$)`

Basically, this puts in an optional quote at the start and makes a capture group out of it, as `("?)`, and uses the backreference `\1` later in the regex to make sure matched content should either be surrounded by quotes, or not have them at all.

The rest is basically some whitespace and then comma-separated content of the format "optional stuff" + "repeating optional stuff starting with a comma", using the "not a quote or comma" group `[^",]` to indicate the actual text content to match.

Capture group #2 will contain the data between the commas you need, trimmed at both sides, and taking all stuff between quotes as one match.

Note that out of necessity to capture the text behind the final comma, I was forced to make all matched content end on "comma OR end of the line", which means multi-line content between quotes (which exists in Excel CSV output) will not be matched correctly.